# dhcpd daemon taking huge amount of memory and restarting with out of memory error

Tags: dhcp, dhcp-server, isc-dhcp, dhcpd, dhcp-option

I have to configure isc-dhcp-server for 1 million clients which listens on 4094 vlan tagged interfaces, where each vlan interface is mapped to a subnet declaration.
Therefore in total 4094 subnet declarations in conf file with 253 clients in each subnet pool.

What I am observing is that dhcpd daemon is taking huge amount of memory and is getting restarted with out of memory error.
I increased the total amount of ram from 8gb to 16 gb(out of which 6 gb are hugepage allocation) still it gradually takes the entire ram and restarts with same error.

Any idea on how much ram I require for 1 million clients or any other way to overcome this issue??

DHCPv4

Comment: if you are serving ipv6 ranges, then maybe this applies to your situation: https://kb.isc.org/article/AA-01464/0/DHCP-uses-too-much-memory%3A-reducing-dhcp-memory-consumption-by-careful-use-of-range6-statements.html

Answer (score 0):

Look at DHCP on LDAP instead of flat files.
But, I would like to explode the service into multiple servers instead of one which crash under load.